# Assembly loading error in my ASP.NET app, and the assembly isn't even referenced anymore

Tags: asp.net, assembly-resolution

I had some code that referenced the Noesis.Javascript assembly (http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com) and had renamed the Noesis.Javascript.dll to Noesis.Javascript.0.4.dll.  I referenced this file through Visual Studio, and when I launched my web app in the ASP.NET development server, I got this error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Noesis.Javascript.0.4' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's
>   manifest definition does not match the
>   assembly reference. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I then tried to remove this reference and re-reference the older version of the library.  I got the same error.  I then tried to remove this reference entirely and comment out all code that used this library.  I still get the same error.  I have tried to explicitly close out the ASP.NET development server from its icon in the system tray, but this still occurs.  I can find no reference of this assembly anywhere in my project now, yet the error persists.  What might be happening?  Is there some cache that I'm not finding?  How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Go into the registry and set [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.

Refresh the page and the error output will show you which assembly has a dependency on Noesis.Javascript.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Check if "Noesis.Javascript.0.4" appears anywhere in your web.config file and remove it if it does.  It might be in the `<assemblies>` part.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I had already checked on this.  There is no Noesis assembly anywhere in the web.config.

Comment: Did you try clearing the temporary ASP.NET files? C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: I was excited about that idea, but no luck.  I cleared out that folder, made sure the dev servers were shut down, and restarted and got the same error.  I also verified that the app was building with the .NET Framework 4 target.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET web site or and ASP.NET web application?

Answer (score 0):

remove the reference and add it again. Please note that the two dll version must be same. Do not add any later version, if its get registered into your web.config, otherwise you need to remove from there too.

Comment: are you using online refrence??

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added a wrong DLL. Instead of adding 64bit, I added 32bit.

Thanks,